# Matching Int to dataType for Bool

Tags: haskell

I want to create a data type that's either New [Int] or Empty; then I want to use an Int and check if the data type contains the Int. This is probably an extremely simple question but I'm new to creating data types and using them in functions, specifically getting a handle on the syntax; I don't have a grounded understanding of it yet.

```
data New = New [Int]
         | Empty
    deriving Show

check :: Int -> New -> Bool
check x ys
 | x `elem` New ys = True
 | otherwise  = False
```

Comment: What does `Empty` provide that `New []` does not?

Comment: it's worth observing that your `New` type is essentially identical ("isomorphic" in the jargon) to `Maybe [Int]`

Comment: New has an [Int] arg while Empty has no args.

Comment: So I have to address both New [Int] and Empty in the definition?

Comment: Yes, because those are both values of type `New`.

Comment: What I meant was, do you have a situation in mind where you need to distinguish between no list and an empty list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want `check` to pattern-match on its `New` argument to access the underlying list, if any.

```
check :: Int -> New -> Bool
check x Empty = False
check x (New ys) = x `elem` ys
```

One way to collapse the definition a bit is to realize that as far as `check` is concerned, the values `Empty` and `New []` are equivalent.

```
check :: Int -> New -> Bool
check x ys = x `elem` (case ys of
                         New ys' -> ys'
                         Empty -> [])
```

Comment: To test this I write `check 1 (New [1,2,3])` and it comes back True. My question is this: the New I'm using in the test is the type constructor, not the data constructor of the same name?

Comment: @BingoBongo The `New` you use in that line is the data constructor. Type constructors mostly only go in type annotations.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me understand the syntax.

Comment: Until you get used to where type constructors are used and where data constructors are used, you might want to use different names for each: `data New =  NewList [Int] | Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an exercise in using custom data types, I feel like expanding on chepner's question, "What does `Empty` provide that `New []` does not?" since it was not met with any response: Lists can already be empty, so you could make your check without a custom data type definition:

```
check :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
check = elem
```

With the type that Robin said was isomorphic to your `New` type, `Maybe`, it would look like:

```
type New = Maybe [Int]

check :: Int -> New -> Bool
check _ Nothing = False
check x (Just xs) = x `elem` xs
```

Generally when the standard library offers a data type isomorphic to your current one, you should ask yourself if you want to create your own one. Sometimes it is warranted, but often you will want to use either `type` or `newtype` and not `data`.

With this type, `Maybe [Int]`, you must ask yourself why you want to differentiate between `Nothing` and `Just []`. For example, `Nothing` could indicate that the function failed, while `Just []` could indicate that it succeeded, but that the (correct) result was empty.

An example of a function where this makes sense is [the Change exercise on Exercism](https://github.com/exercism/haskell/tree/master/exercises/change):

> Correctly determine the fewest number of coins to be given to a customer such that the sum of the coins' value would equal the correct amount of change.

Here `Nothing` means that it's not possible to give exact change, and `Just []` means that the customer paid the exact amount and needs no change.

If, instead, you'd like some exercises that deal with writing functions for custom data types, see the "W3" exercises on https://github.com/opqdonut/haskell-exercises.

Comment: Thank you! This is a super useful reference.